# Perl CGI displaying as text in browser

Tags: apache, perl, cgi

Perl is displaying as text in browser. Everything is correct.

Part of perl file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

...

# Write sendmailanalyzer header
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Environment Variables</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>";
$CGI->charset($CONFIG{HTML_CHARSET} || $DEFAULT_CHARSET);
print $CGI->header();
print $CGI->start_html(-title=>"sendmailanalyzer v$VERSION");

print qq{
        <!-- javascript to draw graphics -->
                <script type="text/javascript" src="$CONFIG{URL_JSCRIPT}"></script>
                <style type="text/css">
                <!--/* <![CDATA[ */
....and so on
```

httpd.conf

```
        Alias /sareport /usr/local/something/www
        <Directory /usr/local/something/www>
                AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
            Options FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
                DirectoryIndex something.cgi
                Order deny,allow
                Deny from all
                Allow from 127.0.0.1
                Allow from ::1
                Allow from MyIP
        </Directory>
```

Script is set to 755...I am lost on this one. Nothing in the logs.

Running the app from the CLI directly gives back this for the header(it works)

```
 Content-type: text/html

 <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Environment Variables</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

 <!DOCTYPE html
         PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
 <head>
```

Comment: If everything is correct, why does it not work? is your file located in /usr/local/something/www ? Did this work before?

Comment: This is the first time installing this. The file is there as it loads in the browser but as text.

Comment: Have you followed all the steps on: https://github.com/darold/sendmailanalyzer ? Including restarting the http daemon?

Comment: What is the full name of the script? What do the debug logs of Apache say?

Comment: all the debug log says is

    [Thu Jun 19 17:59:20 2014] [debug] mod_deflate.c(602): [client x.x.x.x] Zlib: Compressed 179236 to 27378 : URL /sareport/sa_report.cgi

Comment: Yes I followed the instructions exact.

Comment: Also, when I run from the CLI it runs correctly, I get the header I just added above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, I was setting up the cgi piece correctly, however someone had commented out the actual loading of the module itself

```
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
```

bye now :}